# Slight issue parsing text into html

Tags: python, html, django, twitter, html-parsing

Hmmmm, this may well be an easy one but may well be a complex one. I'm having an issue setting up an SEO friendly Twitter feed within the Django framework. Most of the heavy lifting is done as a template tag `blog_tags.py` file as follows:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/frame/twitter.html')
def show_latest_tweets():
    tweets = []

    try:
        """The import error is here to catch any server migrations were the tweepy package not to be found in site_packages"""
        import tweepy
    except:
        tweets.append({'status': 'There was a problem referencing our tweets. Please inform our webmaster.', 'relative_date': 'Just now'})
        raise ImportError

    # OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settings.EOS_TWITTER_FEED['EOS_FEED_TWITTER_KEY'], settings.EOS_TWITTER_FEED['EOS_FEED_TWITTER_SECRET'])
    auth.set_access_token(settings.EOS_TWITTER_FEED['EOS_FEED_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'], settings.EOS_TWITTER_FEED['EOS_FEED_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'])

    # Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    user = 'FFXVEN'

    avatar_url = api.get_user(screen_name='@'+user).profile_image_url

    i = 0
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@'+user).items():
        if 'RT' not in tweet.text:
            if i <= 4:
                status = tweet.text
                hashtags = [word for word in status.split() if word[0] == "#"]

                #Find hashtags in tweet and create a string to contain <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=" + hashtag>#hashtag</a>
                for hashtag in hashtags:
                    if hashtag.endswith((',',';','.')):
                        hashtag = hashtag[:-1]

                    status = status.replace(hashtag, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q={}">{}</a>'.format(hashtag[1:], hashtag))

                relative_date = tweet.created_at
                tweets.append({'user': user, 'avatar_url': avatar_url, 'status': html.unescape(status), 'relative_date': relative_date})
                i += 1
            else:
                break
        else:
            continue

    return { "tweets": tweets }
```

All works well - it returns everything I want and currently it strips the hashtags out and replaces them with Twitter friendly hashtags. HOWEVER, client side this is what is displayed:

[image]

I'm stuck on how I would work it such that client side the html elements are rendered as html elements and not pre-formatted text?

Comment: show your template where you are displaying

Comment: Standard for tweet in tweets loop with {{ tweet.status }} variable displayed in a <p></p> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ tweet.status|safe }
```

try the safe template filter

Comment: Awesome - will try this.